# Android Application connection to and already built in database of a website

Tags: android, database, web-services

I am new to android and I want to make an E-commerce website, someone else has made the website of that project so I have to use the same database, My question is that how can I connect my android app to that data base?

Ps: I thought this would work using a web service?
    And by going through tutorials, there is one that saying make your android app according to the database?

Now I am confused how to do this , If anyone can help , Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very nice question. A website that already has a database established but would like to be cross platform (connecting android,iOS etc) to your app so that it cannot only communicate with data but also exchange it with your website. The most preferred way that's perfect for a task like this (also which many websites use) is known as..

**API** Application Programming Interface.

Since you already have your website hosted on a server with a database. You have to create an API for android etc to communicate with the main website.

Through **API** **POST** and **GET** calls. Data is transferred in form of **JSON** . Don't let this whole process seem scary its easier than it sounds.

All you need is to create a secure API and host it on your server too. Android will post to the database using the API.

To get started on this check out

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

I Will also like you to google out **firebase** also a back end service for this.

Comment: Thank you so much. One thing I'd like to add is that its basically a group project and one of the member is making website and database and he is a bit step ahead from us so website is not hosted yet.. so is there any specific thing you like to tell??

Comment: Do You mean you guys are creating/testing the website on localhost on PC and yet to host it? Well you can still make the API its just same. He has to make all objects/API work too all you have to do use the API in your android

Comment: Thanks too goodluck with your project, make sure you checkout the website in answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
    Native Android app cannot directly communicate with external database as it is in server

Moreover all the required service might have been written in the form of webservice either in PHP/Java/.Net in the server. Those webservice might be returning **JSONs**.

Without http but by using **Volley or Retrofit** one can consume the webservice available in the server and can use in the android app

Webservices will be in the form of http only
 Eg : http://..../getRelayStatus.jsp?scannedId=1234 where getRelayStatus.jsp is the service written and available in server
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many libraries that help you to do that.

First, you need to build APIs using that database.(Web service)

Then you need to use HTTP clients to call get APIs to get that data

from your database. I recommend Retrofit2 or Volley libraries.

Make model classes so you can map the data tables.

Now you can make your ListView or RecyclerView to hold that data

in your Android application.

Comment: Thank you so much. One thing I'd like to add is that its basically a group project and one of the member is making website and database and he is a bit step ahead from us so website is not hosted yet.. so is there any specific thing you like to tell??

Comment: if the website/database is ready and isnt hosted yet, he can simply share his source code so each of your team member can host it on localhost and experiment

Comment: Or simply just host the website.. can be easier that way